# Alternative to Custom Organizational Email Alerts

Tags: email, events, notifications, alert

We have a bunch of applications that all need to notify someone which is currently be done with **email distribution lists**. We would like to not have to hardcore config files with SMTP and receipt information in every single application that need to alert the business.

We would like to change this so we can centralize and archive notifications by applications (for investigating problems).  Something like a publish/subscriber model instead of direct send.

**Does anyone know if a service free or paid that we can have all our applications use to broadcast events/send to subscribers?**